# How does L2 regularization make weights smaller?

Tags: machine-learning, proofs, hyper-parameters, regularization, l2-regularization

I'm learning logistic regression and $L_2$ regularization.
The cost function looks like below.

$$J(w) = -\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n} (y^{(i)}\log(\phi(z^{(i)})+(1-y^{(i)})\log(1-\phi(z^{(i)})))$$

And the regularization term is added. ($\lambda$ is a regularization strength)

$$J(w) = -\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n} (y^{(i)}\log(\phi(z^{(i)})+(1-y^{(i)})\log(1-\phi(z^{(i)}))) + \frac{\lambda}{2}\| w \|$$

Intuitively, I know that if $\lambda$ becomes bigger, extreme weights are penalized and weights become closer to zero. However, I'm having a hard time to prove this mathematically.

$$\Delta{w} = -\eta\nabla{J(w)}$$
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial{w_j}}J(w) = (-y+\phi(z))x_j + \lambda{w_j}$$
$$\Delta{w} = \eta(\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n}(y^{(i)}-\phi(z^{(i)}))x^{(i)} - \lambda{w_j})$$

This doesn't show the reason why incrementing $\lambda$ makes weight become closer to zero. It is not intuitive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my take.

The larger the $\lambda$, the more the corresponding regularization term for a coefficient will be big, so when minimizing the cost function, the coefficient will be reduced by a bigger factor, you can see this effect in the derivation of the update rule for gradient descent for example:
\begin{align*} \theta_j := \theta_j - \alpha\ \left[ \left( \frac{1}{m}\ \sum_{i=1}^m (h_\theta(x^{(i)}) - y^{(i)})x_j^{(i)} \right) + \frac{\lambda}{m}\theta_j \right] &\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ j \in \lbrace 1,2...n\rbrace\newline & \end{align*}

\begin{align*} \theta_j := \theta_j (1- \alpha \frac{\lambda}{m})\left( \frac{\alpha}{m}\ \sum_{i=1}^m (h_\theta(x^{(i)}) - y^{(i)})x_j^{(i)} \right) &\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ j \in \lbrace 1,2...n\rbrace\newline & \end{align*}

From this derivation, it is clear that at every update the coefficients get **reduced** by a factor that is usually a little less than 1 and **directly proportional to $\lambda$**, so, as $\lambda$ gets bigger, the weights get reduced more and more; eventually, for very big values of $\lambda$, we risk to totally underfit the data, since only the regularization term will remain in the cost function and all the weights will go to zero.

This is for linear regression, but it is essentially the same logic also for logistic regression.

This is taken from [Andrew Ng's course on Coursera](https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning/supplement/pKAsc/regularized-linear-regression). A more mathematical precise (and complex) traction of the problem can be found in [the Bloomberg machine learning course material](https://bloomberg.github.io/foml/#lecture-6-l1-and-l2-regularization).

PS: in the derivation of the update rule for gradient descent, the $\lambda$ should be divided by the number of training examples, this is important in choosing the right $\lambda$ because we want this relationship to be inversely proportional, otherwise the coefficient won't be decreased.